# Can finding a left-inverse be formulated as a problem of choosing from a set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, category-theory

**Motivation.** Let $A, B, C$ be sets and $g:B\to C$ and $h:A\to B$. For each $a\in A$ we have the set $X_a:=\{b\in B\mid g(b)=h(a)\}\subseteq B$. This is in fact a function $X:A\to \mathcal P(B)$ into the power set of $B$, given by $a\mapsto X_a$. Now, a function $f:A\to B$ satisfies $g\circ f = h$ if and only if $\forall a\in A:f(a)\in X_a$.

**Question.** I wonder if this is also true in the following, similar, situation: Let $f:A\to B$ and $h:A\to C$ be given. Is there a function $X:B\to \mathcal P(C)$ such that a $g:B\to C$ satisfies $g\circ f = h$ if and only if $\forall b\in B: g(b)\in X_b$.

Comment: In the "motivation" isn't codomain of $h$ supposed to be $C$?

Comment: There exists $X$ as in the question if and only if $f(a)=f(a') \Rightarrow h(a)=h(a')$, and then $X_b= h(g^{-1}(\{b\})$.